# Double filtering with for loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I’m trying to essentially double filter this “championships” dataset for each element of the “questions” column and then for the elements of the “correct” column (either 1 or 0). I have tried to do this with the code below:

```
unique_questions <- unique(championships$question)
question_ <- numeric(length(unique_questions))
for(i in unique_questions) {{
  question_[i] <- championships %>% filter(question == i)
}
  
correct_ <- length(championships$correct)
for(j in unique_correct) {
  correct_[j] <- championships %>% filter(correct == j)                  
}                    
  print(question_[i], correct_[j])
}
```

This doesn’t seem to be working and I have a feeling the problem has something to do with the placement of brackets of the choice of functions (in particular, the numeric(length()) function) within the for loops. If this function worked properly, I would hope to have elements of a form similar to qc_ij with i drawn from the “unique_questions” category and j drawn from the “unique_correct” category. There are twelve questions and two choices of “correct” (1 and 0) so I would hope there would be 24 objects of type qc_ij. If someone sees where this functions doesn’t work, can you help me fix it?

Comment: Your dynamic creation of `question_[i]` and `correct_[j]` won't work. Check the `assign` function for how to dynamically create objects.

Comment: Would it suffice to use: `library(dplyr); championships %>% group_by(question, correct) %>% slice(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to store the unique questions and answers for each step and you can filter a data.frame simply by selecting rows that satisfy a certain condition:

```
for(q in unique(championships$question)){
  d = championships[championships$question==q,] ## Filter for q
  for (ci in unique(d$correct)) { ## Only loop over the possible answers for THIS question
    d2 = d[d$correct=ci,]  ## Filter for ci

    ## Just print it to see whether it worked
    print(paste(q,ci))
    print(d2)
  }
}
```

So, you subsequently get all the subsets of the championships table for each value of questions and each value of (specific) correct answers.